# can't get checkbox to uncheck when dropdown set 0

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, checkbox

I'm trying to add these functionalities to my ordering form

1. when **checkbox** is checked then **Qty dropdown** value will change to 1
2. when **checkbox** is unchecked then **Qty dropdown** value will change to 0
3. when **Qty dropdown** value set to anything but 0 **checkbox** will change to checked
4. when **Qty dropdown** value set to 0 then **checkbox** will uncheck

I've got most of it working,
but I cant get #4 to work - checkbox won't uncheck when dropdown set to 0.

here is the code [codepen](https://codepen.io/meirroth/pen/KrzeRR)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".product input:checkbox").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).siblings("select").val(1);
    } else {
      $(this).siblings("select").val(0);
    }
  });
  $(".product select").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val != '0') {
      $(this).siblings("input:checkbox").prop("checked", true);
    }else{
      $(this).siblings("input:checkbox").prop("checked", false);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `val()` function not the `val` property to get the value

```
if ($(this).val() != '0') {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `$(element).prop()` [jQuery Documentation about prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)
You can also use prop for setting element values, see docs for more Info.

```
if ( $(this).prop('selected') ) {
  // your code ...
}
```

or check for the selectedIndex

```
$(element).prop('selectedIndex', 0);
```